# r0 vs ro in transistors ac modeling?

Tags: transistors, bjt, modeling

I'm a beginner in electronics field . In hybrid and pi and T models we have a resistance called r0 or ro . What's the correct name ? Is it "r-zero" or "r-o  (15th alphabet letter)". Pls give references . Different people say different stuff !

Thanks ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a subscripted letter O. \$r_o\$ is the output resistance of the transistor. It represents the fact that the transistor is not an ideal voltage-controlled current source. The collector/drain voltage does have some influence on the current, and that's what \$r_o\$ models.

Answer (score 0):

Ro is the output resistance, so it should be the letter O and not the number 0.

For instance on the wikipedia page for the hybrid pi model (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid-pi_model) it shows Ro as being the output resistance of the Early Effect.

Answer (score 0):

In the models you are referring to, ro (as in the letter) is short hand notation for Resistance Output. More specifically this resistance is due to the Early Effect.

Comment: Because it is a dynamic (differential) resistance you always should write ro (instead of Ro).

Comment: @LvW, In my opinion, "ro" is (1) static resistance that (2) changes dynamically to obtain (3) linear (4) differential resistance:) Happy New year!

Comment: To me, a "static resistance" is the ratio of two DC quantities - in this case: Vce/Ic, Happy and healthy New Year to you.

Comment: @LvW, Exactly... and this ratio dynamically changes... so its IV curve rotates... and the cross (operating) point depictures the transistor output (differential resistance) IV curve... that is also linear... but does not pass through the coordinate origin... and has some slope due to Early effect... Interesting phenonemon... Regards.